# The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, removing hypothesis

Tags: analysis

I am trying to understand why the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is written the way it is done in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part).
So, I go removing hypothesis and check if anything breaks. First check: are there functions $f:[a,b]→ℝ$ and $F:[a,b]→ℝ$ such that $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$ (i.e. $F'(x) = f(x)$ for $x\in(a,b)$) and
$$
(1)\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad  \int^b_a f(t) dt = F(b) - F(a)
$$
yet $f$ is not Riemann integrable?
The left side of equation (1) would not even have meaning without the hypothesis ‘$f$ is Riemann integrable’.
Trying to savage the maimed theorem, let us say that the integral can be Lebesgue. Then, the usual ‘$f(x) = 0$ when $x$ is irrational and $f(x) = 1$ when $x$ is rational’ comes to mind. But that function does not have a derivative. Hence two questions:

1. Are the derivative and the Riemann integral so related to each other that the FTC cannot be expanded to other types of integrals?
2. If not, what is the anti-Lebesgue-integral? (in the same way that derivation would be the anti-Riemann-integral)

Comment: [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) is a differentiable function whose derivative is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: You do not need the function to be the derivative, you need it to be the anti-derivative, but it is still correct that that $f$ has no anti-derivative.

Comment: Notice that the FTC only guarantees that: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=f(x)$$When $f$ is continuous. Differentiation is not "anti" to integration even for Riemannian case if you allow discontinuous functions

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you! It is always interesting to have examples that show how ‘tight’ theorems are.

Comment: You might be interested in [Henstock-Kurzwiel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral). Its definition does not differ significantly from the definition of Riemann integral, but the H-K integral can integrate any derivative :).